# CUPS-filter :what is CUPS developer packages

Tags: c++, cups

CUPS-filter:1.21.6
CUPS:2.3.0
when i "./configure",it allways tells me "Required cups-config is missing. Please install CUPS developer packages." ,but  i don't know what "CUPS developer packages" is. I've been looking for it for a long time

Comment: What is your Linux distribution?

Comment: Linux  version 4.19.0-desktop-amd64 (deepin@deepin-PC) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Uos 8.3.0.3-3+rebuild))

Comment: That's not what a Linux distribution is. A Linux distribution would be: Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian, etc...

Comment: sorry.my linux distribution is UnionTech OS Desktop 20 Pro

Comment: A Google search reveals that to be some custom Linux distribution used in China. Only someone else who is knowledgeable with that specific Linux distribution will know how to install the CUPS development package on that Linux distribution.

Comment: i tried it on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS,the result is the same.

Comment: You need to install smth like cups-*-dev on Ubuntu. The asterisks are placeholders for version numbers.